# Regular border + offset border on button using CSS

Tags: html, css, button, web, frontend

[css button with double border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzVTw.png)

I'm trying to acheive the same border effect on the button above.

The closest I can get is the following, but the bottom right corner of the bottom border is not properly rounded:

>

```
.login__button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-width: 2px 1px 2px 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: pink;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: pink;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 33px;
  width: 102px;
  box-shadow:
    3.5px 4px 0px black,
    1.5px 0px 0px pink,
    3.5px 4px 0px black,
    2px 6px 0px pink;
}

.login__button::before {
  background: pink;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 35px;
  width: 3.0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 3%;
  right: -2.8px;
}
```

>

I feel like this should be possible using just box-shadows but there doesnt appear to be a way to modify the width of the box shadow to get just the black portion inset properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the idea is to make the `.login__button:before` basically look the same as `.login__button`, but to change the positioning, and to give it a lower `z-index` than `.login__button`.

```css
.login__button {
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid #FF00A0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #FF00A0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 102px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.login__button:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid #FF00A0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgb(255,0,160);
}
.login__button:active {
  background-color: gold;
}
.login__button:active:before {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<button class="login__button">LOG IN</button>
```

And just for the sake of it, I've added a style for then the button is pressed.

```
.login__button:active {
  background-color: gold;
}
.login__button:active:before {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt.

```css
.login__button {
  background: black;
  border: 4px solid #FF69B4;
  color: #FF69B4;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
 }

.login__button::before {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  border: 4px solid #FF69B4;
  margin-left: -4px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 12px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="login__button">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but here's what I'd probably do.

```css
#a, #b{
  border: 2px solid magenta;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#a{
  border-top: none;
  width: 20%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px magenta;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, magenta 0%, black 24%);
}
#b{
  color: magenta;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
<div id='b'>
Button
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body { padding: 50px; }

.login__button {
  border: 2px solid fuchsia;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: fuchsia;
  background: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 33px;
  width: 102px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px 8px rgba(227,37,243,0.3);
}

.login__button::before {
  background: black;
  border: 2px solid fuchsia;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  bottom: -7px;
  left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<button class="login__button">LOG IN</button>
```